# Binding label Content and MouseDoubleClick with query results

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm new to WPF.
I have a simple form containing some Topics in the Label component.
I want to double click on them and open the details form.

```xml
<Grid>
  <WrapPanel>
     <Label Content="{Binding jbTopic}" MouseDoubleClick="Details"/>
  </WrapPanel>       
</Grid>
```

behind code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var Query1 = from r1 in mydb.Jobs
        join u in mydb.Users on r1.Cid equals u.ID
        where r1.Status == "Active"
        select new
        {
            jbTopic = r1.Topic
            jbCreator = u.FullName
            jbID=r1.ID
        };    
}

private void Details(int id){}
```

when I use Datagrid and set a source, I can see the result.
but I want to have it in label content and also I want to have related MouseDoubleClick Method calling by jbID.

Answer (score 0):

is there any other way to do this job?
in fact I need some clickable component which content/Text can be read from a query result. and dynamic Method calling.